# How do I modify my Python code to separate sentiments from tweets

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

**Problem**
I am a beginner to Python coding and wrote a piece of code that performs sentiment analysis on tweets. The results are displayed as follows :
TWEETS (POLARITY_SCORE, SUBJECTIVITY_SCORE)

Now, I want to write my results to a CSV file with 3 columns where the first column should be the tweets, the second column should be polarity and the last column subjectivity score. However being new to Python I couldn't figure out how to go about it. I tried some different random techniques but I did not get the desired results. Any help (simple explanation should be enough) in this regard would be of great help.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

# Create the authentication package
consumer_key = "yiOewPXCYY86sHHKMPUcUP5qj"
consumer_secret = "FtSA31g45eZvpT9OJ6kIPOYjGFjYgTdd9BHDDNr8p0RW8AYW5V"

access_token = "1016268651211603968-6IAk4SCDprCT83xrsucA9fVBqr1RYF"
access_token_secret = "KDQgUklgB08tcfrPL4pCbD3WcuT9N2emuXZ20fhdjSYM5"

# Authenticate the app 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Search for tweets
public_tweets = api.search("Trump")


for tweets in public_tweets :

    # Print the tweets
    print(tweets.text)

    # Perform sentiment analysis on tweets
    analysis = TextBlob(tweets.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    print("")
```

What I thought was analysis.sentiment[0] was storing the polarity while analysis.sentiment[1] was storing the subjectivity, however when I tried to do the same and print the results, my answers were different from what I was expecting.

**OPTIONAL DOUBT (THIS QUESTION NEED NOT HAVE AN ANSWER RIGHT NOW)**

What would be my approach if I wanted to check if the polarity is greater than a specified value how would I do that?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? It seems like you're asking a lot of things at once. "How do I write a csv file?" and "why am I getting output different from what I'm expecting?" and "how do I tell if one number is greater than another number?" and "what value should I consider the boundary between positive and negative sentiment"? If someone knows the answer to one of these but not the others, they might elect to stay quiet. For this reason, it's best to ask one question per post.

Comment: Also, you really should not be publishing any API keys anywhere. Ever. You should remove those and set them as environment variables.

Comment: I thought if I gave API keys then it would help people run the code directly without them having to go through the trouble of creating their own app for the same.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the update, changes have been made!

Comment: I don't know much about twitter or sentiment analysis, but if you get to the point where you're ready to write your results to a csv file, the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module is very helpful.